# HTML Living Standard の変更点の見方がわかりません

Tags: html, html5

HTML Living StandardはW3Cで公開されているHTML5.1,HTML5.2のようなマイナーバージョンがなく、常にアップデートされていく仕様かと思います。

HTML Living Standardの公式ドキュメントおよび日本語訳版を見ても、
いつ何が追加になったのか、削除されたのか（差分）がわかりません。
どこを見れば差分がわかるのでしょうか？
GitHubを見てそこから読み取るしかないのでしょうか？

#### HTML Living Standard

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/

#### 日本語訳版

https://momdo.github.io/html/

W3Cで公開されているHTMLとDOMは将来廃止される予定で、今後HTMLとDOMのWEB標準はHTML Living Standardになるとのことで、HTML Living Standardをしっかり追いかけていかないとなと思っているのですが、見方がわからず少々困っております。

ご教示よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

バージョンがなくバージョン間の差異のまとめもないため、規格の変更を知りたい場合は、gitのコミットを見ていくしかないと思います。

今後の変更を追うなら、https://github.com/whatwg/html/commits/master.atom をRSSリーダなどで購読するといいかも知れません。